# MySQL dump compatibility issue (from 4.0.26 into 5.5.41)

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I am trying to transfer data from MySQL 4.0.26 into MySQL 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.

I am making a dump from MySQL 5.5 server via `mysqldump` it works but when I'm trying to restore it there a problem occures:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 20: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 4
```

Is there some way how to create compatible dump for MySQL 5.5. from MySQL 4.0?

Comment: Newer MySQL versions use the keyword `ENGINE` instead of `TYPE`. Maybe you can try to search & replace it in the dump file (not quite a good idea if the dump file has several gigabytes).

Comment: see [here](http://matthiaslienau.de/blog/2013/6/21/converting-mysql4-database-dump-syntax-to-mysql5)

Comment: @axiac I don't see a problem in there. Just replace it right when mysqldump writes the dump file.

Comment: @fancyPants - do you have a some tip how to do it when mysqldump creates the dump file? Now I'm looking for a solution how to replace (Linux) keywords in my 2GB dump file.

Comment: Use `mysqldump --no-data` to dump only the database structure in a file (`structure.sql`). Use `sed -i s/TYPE=/ENGINE=/g structure.sql` to replace `TYPE` with `ENGINE`. Import the structure. Export only the data using `mysqldump --no-create-info`; import it on the other server.

Comment: It seems there is another issue with `enum` type: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1027: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(10) NOT NULL,
  `view_lock` enum('y','n') NOT NULL default 'n',
  PRIMARY KEY  ' at line 8`. Do I will have to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
mysqldump ... | sed 's/TYPE=/ENGINE=/g' |  > dump_file
```

(...and be enough. In the link Jens posted, there's another substitute for timestamp(14), but MySQL does this automatically, if I'm not mistaken.)